# How to combine linq queries and selecting distinct records?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-4.1

I have an object that can have a single user assigned to it or a work group. A user may be assigned directly or though a work group, but the object can never have both set.

```
public class Procedure
{
      .....
      public Guid? AssignedToId {get;set;} //Foreign Key to AssignedTo
      public Contact AssignedTo {get;set;} //Single user assignment
      public Guid? AssignedWorkGroupId {get;set;} //Foreign Key to AssignedWorkGroup
      public WorkGroup AssignedWorkGroup {get;set;} //Multiple user assignment
      public Guid? AssignedBuisnessPartnerId {get;set;}
      public BusinessPartner AssignedBuisnessPartner {get;set;}

}
```

I am trying to figure out how to write a single query where I can find procedures where a user may be assigned directly or is part of a work group that is assigned. Currently I have 2 separate queries and combining the lists I get back. Which works, but probably not as efficient.

Here is what I have now:

```
var procedures =  _procedureRepository.Get(p => p.AssignedToId == assignedId).ToList();

procedures.AddRange(_procedureRepository.Get(p => p.AssignedWorkGroup.Contacts.Select(c => c.Id).Contains(assignedId) || p.AssignedBuisnessPartner.Contacts.Select(c => c.Id).Contains(assignedId));
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us your two queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a `Union All` in sql, which is equivalent to [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755.aspx) in linq. The following code will only execute one call to the database. Not sure if it will be faster than your current method.

```
var procedures2 = _procedureRepository.Get(p => p.AssignedWorkGroup.Contacts
                                                                   .Select(c => c.Id)
                                                                   .Contains(assignedId) || 
                                                p.AssignedBuisnessPartner.Contacts
                                                                         .Select(c => c.Id)
                                                                         .Contains(assignedId));

var procedures = _procedureRepository.Get(p => p.AssignedToId == assignedId)
                                     .Concat(procedures2);
```